# Best way to handle an interrupt signal in server app?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

What is the best way to handle an interrupt signal in infinite loop in server application?

I develop simple FTP Server where every client has its own thread. And now, what I want to do is to handle interrupt signal and then interrupt every thread in the vector of client threads.
In every thread I want to have an opportunity to send to client some response while sending/receiving some file and manually close socket. In main thread I want to only log that server was aborted and close server socket.

I had an idea to implement my server class FTPServer like singleton and in `signal()` call a function which calls method `abort()` of FTPServer instance. But I don't know what it will do when the main infinite loop is still running and `accept()` is still waiting for a new client ... And this pattern I can not use in client threads because there are not only one instance ..

My methods are:

```
void FTPServer::run() {     
    while ( 1 ){      
            int cliFd = TCPController::acceptClient ( m_serverFD );

            serveNewClient(cliFd);
       }    
}
void FTPServer::serveNewClient( int clientFD ){    
    m_client_threads.push_back( thread(&FTPServer::clientThread, *this,  clientFD) );
}

void FTPServer::clientThread( int clientFD ){
    ClientThread client(clientFD);
    client.run();    
}
```

So I want to handle interrupt signal, break(?) the main infinite loop and call abort() method.
I was searching for something like this:

```
void FTPServer::run() {    
    try{
        while ( 1 ){      
                int cliFd = TCPController::acceptClient ( m_serverFD );

                serveNewClient(cliFd);
            }    
    catch( RuntimeException & e ){
        this.abort()
    }
}
```

But I didn't find anything .. :(

In every client thread I have infinite loop too - it waits for client's commands ...

So, please, can you tell me, what is the best way to handle it?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple threads, each with its own loop. What you should do is make sure your thread loops frequently check to see if they should be aborted. So instead of blocking indefinitely on `acceptClient`, accept a connection with a timeout. When the timeout expires, or when a connection is accepted, check if the thread should quit.